# Using pointgrey camera in simulation environment

Tags: ros, simulation, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using the jackal from Clearpath robotics.
I have installed the required packages and drivers for the pointgrey camera.
I wanted to be able to use the camera in simulation environment with gazebo.
How do I launch the camera in the simulation environment.
I followed the instructions at:
http://www.clearpathrobotics.com/assets/guides/ros/ROS%20Navigation%20Basics.html#customization

These speak of using the custom urdf file for camera specs. But when I do a roslaunch after that, I get the following error:

```
Xacro conditional "$(optenv JACKAL_URDF_EXTRAS 0)" to: evaluated"/home/bru/dev/SensorFusionAndControl/BasicJackalNavigation/src/jackal/jackal_description/urdf/custom_example.urdf", which is not a boolean expression.

when processing file:    
/home/bru/dev/SensorFusionAndControl/BasicJackalNavigation/src/jackal/jackal_description/urdf/jackal.urdf.xacro

while processing /home/bru/dev/SensorFusionAndControl/BasicJackalNavigation/src/jackal/jackal_description/launch/description.launch:
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [/opt/ros/indigo/lib/jackal_description/env_run
/home/bru/dev/SensorFusionAndControl/BasicJackalNavigation/src/jackal/jackal_description/urdf/configs/base /opt/ros/indigo/lib/xacro/xacro /home/bru/dev/SensorFusionAndControl/BasicJackalNavigation/src/jackal/jackal_description/urdf/jackal.urdf.xacro --inorder] returned with code [2].

Param xml is:
"param command="$(find jackal_description)/scripts/env_run $(find jackal_description)/urdf/configs/$(arg config) $(find xacro)/xacro $(find jackal_description)/urdf/jackal.urdf.xacro --inorder" name="robot_description"

The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

What am I not doing here?
Please help and advise.

Regards,
rsmitha.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268739/using-pointgrey-camera-in-simulation-environment/) by [rsmitha](https://answers.ros.org/users/28985/rsmitha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-08-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems that the script *jackal_description/urdf/jackal.urdf.xacro* is not using properly [Xacro's conditional blocks](http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Conditional_Blocks)

You can see it by yourself [looking at the code](https://github.com/jackal/jackal/blob/966760fe28f6a6044806699bdd1448952426cfb4/jackal_description/urdf/jackal.urdf.xacro#L198):

```
  <!-- Optional custom includes. -->
  <xacro:if value="$(optenv JACKAL_URDF_EXTRAS 0)">
    <xacro:include filename="$(env JACKAL_URDF_EXTRAS)" />
  </xacro:if>
```

Xacros's conditional block (xacro:if) expects *value* to be 0, 1, true or false. When the environment variable JACKAL_URDF_EXTRAS is not set then `$(optenv JACKAL_URDF_EXTRAS 0)` evaluates to 0 (which is correct), but when you do `export JACKAL_URDF_EXTRAS=~/somepath` it evaluates to *~/somepath* (which makes xacro:if fail)

A possible solution would be:

In addition to `export JACKAL_URDF_EXTRAS=...` (according to http://www.clearpathrobotics.com/assets/guides/ros/ROS%20Navigation%20Basics.html#customization) also do:

```
export USE_JACKAL_URDF_EXTRAS=1
```

And then change the code in *jackal_description/urdf/jackal.urdf.xacro* to:

```
  <!-- Optional custom includes. -->
  <xacro:if value="$(optenv USE_JACKAL_URDF_EXTRAS 0)">
    <xacro:include filename="$(env JACKAL_URDF_EXTRAS)" />
  </xacro:if>
```

This will tell *jackal_description/urdf/jackal.urdf.xacro* to load  JACKAL_URDF_EXTRAS when USE_JACKAL_URDF_EXTRAS is set to 1 or true.

I hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2017-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rsmitha](https://answers.ros.org/users/28985/rsmitha/) on 2017-08-14**:
Thanks, Martin. It works. I can see the topics related to camera information being published under /image_raw.

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2017-08-14**:
I am glad it worked, enjoy!